# Minimum swaps to create an alternating binary string of ones and zeros

Tags: binary, swap

Given a binary string, that is it contains only 0s and 1s (number of zeros equals the number of ones)  We need to make this string a sequence of alternate characters by **swapping** some of the bits, our goal is to minimize the number swaps.

For example, for the string "00011011" the minimum number of swaps is 2, one way to do it is:

1) swap the bits :                       0001**10**11 --->> 0001**01**11

2) swap the bits(after the first swap) : 0**0**0101**1**1 --->> 0**1**0101**0**1

Note that if we are given the string "00101011" we can turn it into an alternate string starting with 0 (that requires 3 swaps) and also into alternate string starting with 1 ( that requires one swap - the first and the last bits ).
So the minimum in this case is one swap.

The end goal is to return the minimum number of swaps for a given string of ones and zeros.
What is the most efficient way to solve it?

Comment: What have you already tried to solve it? What went wrong? As it stands, this is overly broad. If you already have a working solution, but it's just too inefficient, you should post this on Code Review to have your code reviewed.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't come up with a good strategy to solve it, should I try every possible swap and check if it leads to the solution? that doesn't seem very good...

Answer (score 0):

Trivial stuff is trivial.

1. xor your sequence with `010101010…`. Note: if the sequence was already "correct", you'd get an all-`0` bit stream (also do with the inverse if you don't care whether you start with `0` or `1`). XOR is very efficient on modern CPUs. I can do [512 bits at a time on my Xeon](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_xor_epi32&techs=AVX2,AVX_512&expand=3041,5669), and I think it takes 2 cycles.
2. count the ones (#ones). On modern x87, and a lot of other ISAs, there's a POPCNT instruction that makes that extremely efficient. Throughput one, 64 bits at a time on my CPU.
3. swaps necessary is #ones/2 (obvious), or #zeros/2, whichever is less.

Note: [Code published on this site is CC-by-SA](https://stackexchange.com/legal#3SubscriberContent). That means that you're legally required to state the URL of this answer and my username when you use this in your software, or your homework, or your exam, or your assignment.